# IBM DOORS Integration with HP ALM 11.5

Tags: java, web-services, rest, ibm-doors

I've got requirement to integrate IBM Doors tool with HP ALM

Is there any API(webservies) from IBM DOORS, which i can implement using java.

I need to pull up all the requirements from the DOORS using java and create the requirements in the ALM.

Comment: What version of DOORS are you using, and do you have DOORS Web Access as well?

Comment: Hello Steve, I am using DOORS 9.5.2 and I do not have DOORS web access

Comment: There is a (commercial) Java wrapper. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31019816/java-program-for-ibm-doors/31045053#31045053) for details.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately without having DOORS Web Access there isn't a direct way to access DOORS using java or a web interface. You could build something in DXL that you launch in a batch mode through Java, but you would need to include login information in the code which would not be very secure. It would also not be very efficient.

If you stood up a DWA server you would be able to use OSLC to communicate with DOORS. If you are looking for more information on that, check out `open-services.net`.

Hope this information helps.

Answer (score 0):

I've written DXL Script to iterate over the Module and pull all requirements from doors. and send them to my java webservice using soap request from DXL

Then I've added trigger , on module close to send the data.. each time module closes..

Answer (score 0):

IBM Doors and HP ALM can be integrated using an out-of-box integration solution called OpsHub Integration Manager.