# Java program for IBM Doors

Tags: ibm-doors

I recently started using IBM Doors program, I also did start writing scripts for it in DXL. However when I checked the eclipse main page, I realized that a tool called MDAccess for Doors exsists. My question is that is it possible to write code in java for Doors if so, what are the disadvantages compared to DXL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to write Java code for DOORS. You already found the solution: MDAccess is a commercial product provided by [Sodius](http://sodius.com/products-overview/mdaccess). According to the [product specs](http://sodius.com/products-overview/mdaccess-doors) and some [marketing presentation](http://de.slideshare.net/0228236060/sodius-md-access-for-doorsv5?related=1) it provides access to a DOORS server using the Java programming language.

Sodius sent me this information on personal request, indicating a disadvantage which might concern you:

> Our Java layer is done to manipulate DOORS data, meaning read/write
>   DOORS data. You will not find Java wrappers of DXL functions that
>   interact with DOORS UI for example.
>
> Note we are able to execute DXL code trough the Java layer so you can
>   always get this mean to achieve DXL-based operations.

However, it's not too cheap.

Answer (score 0):

This might interest you, as it is using available APIs and does not rely on additional commercial products:

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/oslc-services-rational-doors/index.html

---

<sup>**Disclaimer**: 
I work for IBM DOORS product support, however all information posted here is done so in a personal, private capacity and does not necessarily reflect the position of my employer. Therefore what I post does not constitute an official statement by IBM nor is any endorsement of the information by IBM to be assumed, implied or otherwise.
For your own benefit, please do not contact me in a business capacity on this platform, but use the official IBM Support community web portal. Thank you! :-)</sup>